# Erlang: Is there a more elegant way to get a random integer in a specific range, regarding the distribution

Tags: random, erlang, distribution

My approach is the following:

Num 1 and Num 2 are given numbers that the beginning and end of the range,
the resulting random integer can be num 1 or num 2.

```
Num1 + rand:uniform(Num2-Num1).
```

Example:

Num 1 = 3
Num 2 = 20

rand:uniform returns a value between 1 and 17. I then add the Num 1 again,
so the random value is in the given range.

I see the problem with this implementation is the distribution of my random numbers,
because the lowest number in the range has a higher probability, depending on the distance between 0 and num 1 and the range between num 1 and num 2.

I would appreciate a simpler, more elegant solution that distributes the integers uniformly...

Comment: Your logic on uniformity is incorrect.  Adding `Num1` shifts all values along the number line by that amount, but doesn't affect the range or uniformity.  Taking the numbers 1, 2, and 3 and adding 5 to them gives you the numbers 6, 7, and 8.  If you have k of each of the former, you'll have k of each of the latter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `rand:uniform(17)` returns a number between 1 and 17 inclusive, adding 3 to it is going to give a number between 4 and 20.  Try this instead:

```
rand:uniform(Num2 - Num1 + 1) + Num1 - 1
```

If `Num1` is 3 and `Num2` is 20, that will become `rand:uniform(18) + 2`, giving a random number between 3 and 20 inclusive.

Comment: Thank you, that partially answer my question. My solution was incorrect! Still, the distriubtion is unbearable for large numbers. Do you have a solution in mind that distributes uniformly, without having a higher probability on the lowest number?

Comment: The documentation states that the return value is uniformly distributed, so if it's not, it's probably worth submitting a bug report. Are you using Erlang/OTP 22 or newer? The default algorithm [was changed](https://github.com/erlang/otp/pull/1969) in that release.

Comment: I mean yeah, the rand:uniform is uniformly distributed. I hope so...
I thought the distrubtion could be altered, after adding and subtracting the values like in your solution.